# How to add subtitles to video

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to add subtitles inside a video programmatically. Can we dynamically add subtitles to video. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please dont down vote someones question.you can add at least comment for why this question is down voted or better way is to correct it if you have knowledge. I think here its one kind of trend to down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... I had a similar problem when i wanted to display metadata information.
I ended up creating a view overlay and putting the metadata there.
I dont think i encountered any other way in the documentation.

You are going to have a lot more trouble though. If you have a video file, you are going to have to check if a particular point in the video had been reached, and then update the string being shown on the overlay.... Might be a little messy.

Stand by for the smarter ones to come up with a better answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for answer.but this will work with Airplay feature of new iOS4.2

Comment: I was under the impression that you needed 4.3 for airplay.
Ive been using 4.2, and i cannot do (mpmovieplayercontroller_instance).allowsAirplay.
I just get an error.

im not sure if airplay will stream the overlay also. Im guessing you dont have access to a device, or you could have tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try embedding subtitle directly to the video and play it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but it is my question. "How to embed subtitle inside video programmatically"

Comment: you can only try adding overlay view over it

Comment: But Will this overlay view display on remote device(For Airplay)?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do here is add an overlay view and you will be done, i don't think that the movie player class must be having any property or method to add subtitles so adding an overlay view is the best option.